# ListView with a LinearLayout inside a LinearLayout: I want the inner LinearLayout to be always at the bottom of the screen.

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView and a LinearLayout (it contains 2 buttons) inside a LinearLayout (this one is the parent of both).

I want to make the inner LinearLayout (the one which contains 2 buttons) to be always shown on the bottom of the screen, is there anyway to do that.

Currently, the LinearLayout does show at the bottom of the screen.
However if the ListView gets too big, it will fill the whole screen.

Sorry, I don't have the code with me now. But the format looks somehow like this:

```
 <LinearLayout>
<ListView>
</ListView>
<LinearLayout>
<button 1>
<button 2>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: The solution I want is it 1st fits the linearlayout in and then fill the rest of the space with the list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd usually think about using  `RelativeLayout` too, but with a `LinearLayout` you could use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <button 1>
        <button 2>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a RelativeLayout as the outer container for a ListView.
I use to add a **header** TextView and a **footer** one, with another TextView to serve as the **emplty listview** warning.
In your case, the header is not needed and the footer might be a LinearLayout with the buttons you need.

Here's a skeletal implementation of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rlHistory"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButtons"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <!-- Put your buttons HERE -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvwHistory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/llButtons"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_colors"
        android:background="@drawable/list_border"
        style="@style/ListViews"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just add the buttons in their LinearLayout container.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead, more precisely the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` attribute :

```
<RelativeLayout >
    <ListView>
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        // ...
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        // ...>
        <button 1>
        <button 2>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a LinearLayout, one solution might be to set the outer LinearLayout's weightSum property and then set the layout_weight property of the list view and the inner linearLayout to values that properly divide the available space to your like.

If you only have two buttons you might like to do layout_weight="0.75" in the list and layout_weight="0.25" in the inner LinearLayout in case the weightSum of the outer layer was set to 1.

I also think the outer LinearLayout would have to be layout_height set to "match_parent" so it fills all the window, and places the buttons of the inner LinearLayout to the bottom.

It would look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">
        <button 1>
        <button 2>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well the percentage cannot be fixed due to different screen size. It would be better if the button gets rendered and then what ever space is left it will be the listview.